# Перенос строки в Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker

У меня есть такой образ из `Dockerfile`, который отлично работает:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y git && apt-get install -y nginx && rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN echo "server { listen 80; root /data/up1; location / { } }" >> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/front.conf
```

Теперь я хочу сделать так, чтобы все мои изменения были в одном слое, но при этом так, чтобы не получалась огромная строчка. Другими словами, я хочу продолжить выполнение инструкции `RUN` на следующей строке.

Если сделать так:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y git && apt-get install -y nginx && rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
&& echo "server { listen 80; root /data/up1; location / { } }" >> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/front.conf
```

то возникает ошибка `Error response from daemon: Unknown instruction: &&`.
Что делать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

разбить длинную инструкцию в *dockerfile* можно с помощью символа `\` в конце строки:

```
run очень длинная строка \
разбитая на \
несколько строк
```

не забывайте про пробелы! удобнее и нагляднее вставлять его перед `\`

---

пример в документации: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#apt-get